# Unable to exit line in bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to start an application, grep for the word "server startup", exit and then execute the next command. But it would not exit and execute next cmd after condition is met. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash
application start; tail -f /application/log/file/name | \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "Server startup"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
           echo "application started...!"
        fi
done
```

Comment: I don't see any `exit` here. If you are trying to exit the script from within the `while` loop, that won't work because the pipeline (with `tail`) makes that part run in a subshell, and `exit` inside it will only exit the subshell, not the parent shell that's executing the main part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't Use Tail's Follow Flag

Tail's follow flag (e.g. `-f`) will not exit, and will continue to follow the file until it receives an appropriate signal or encounters an error condition. You will need to find a different approach to tracking data at the end of your file, such as `watch`, `logwatch`, or periodic log rotation using `logrotate`. The best tool to use will depend a lot on the format and frequency of your log data.

Comment: Thanks Todd. Any suggestion how this would be written?

Comment: @TeckyRA "The best tool to use will depend a lot on the format and frequency of your log data." If you want a solution, rather than just an explanation of the problem, you're going to have to improve your OP with representative samples of expected input and output. See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information on that.